# $l_p : (p≠2)$ is not an inner product.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am using Kreyszig's functional analysis it is example in it which says that $l_p : (p≠2)$ is not an inner product space. For proof it uses the standard norm on $l_p$ and shows that it does not satisfies parallogram identify.

My question is that what about if we take other norm for example supremum norm on $l_p$, in fact we does not know how many norms we can have on $l_p$ then how checking for only one norm will guarantees it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: $l^p$ is *defined* with a choice of norm. If you use supremum norm on $l^p$ it is no longer $l^p$, but instead $l^\infty$. Moreover, the $l^p$, $l^q$ norms are not equivalent for $p \neq q$. By not equivalent, I mean that different $l^p$ norms induce different topologies on the sequence space.

Comment: But my question is incomplete yet!

Answer (score 2):

A normed linear space comes with a (real or complex) vector space **and** a norm. An inner product space comes with a vector space **and** an inner product. We can understand inner product spaces as normed linear spaces, since inner products induce a norm $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$.

When we say a normed linear space $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ is an inner product space, we (very slightly) abuse terminology. What we mean is that the norm on our normed linear space is induced by some inner product. That is, there exists an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $X$ such that $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle}$ for all $x \in X$. This is true if and only if the norm $\| \cdot \|$ satisfies the parallellogram identity (the "only if" is expected, but the "if" is kinda cool!).

In this case, the $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$ spaces have their own norm equipped, as all normed linear spaces do. If you consider the underlying vector space with a different norm (e.g. the supremum norm), then it is a different normed linear space, and may be an inner product space (it's not hard to see that it isn't for this particular example, but you don't know in general).

As an easy example of this, you can put the $2$-norm on any $\ell^p$ space for $1 \le p < 2$. These are not inner product spaces with their bundled norms, but if you put the $2$-norm on them, then they are inner product spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "their own norm" in 3rd paragraph second line?.....does it means some standard norm on any normes spaces........ secondly my question is that what we exactly mean when we say certain space(without talking about its normal) is not an inner product?

Comment: I mean that $\ell^p$ spaces come with their $p$-norms, and no other norms. You can equp $\ell^p$ with other norms, but this is considered changing the normed linear space. For example, $(\ell^1, \| \cdot \|_1)$ is a different normed linear space to $(\ell^1, \| \cdot \|_2)$. When we talk about $\ell_p$, we are implicitly referring to the pair $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$.

Comment: Okay...thanks a lot

Comment: To answer your second question, if a vector space has no specified norm, then we wouldn't ask whether it is an inner product space. I ***think*** that any real or complex vector space can be made into an inner product space, but I'm not sure. In this case, as I said, $\ell^p$ refers to $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$.

Comment: If you assume the axiom of choice, every vector space can be normed + have an inner product. However, this space is not complete and the topology induced by the inner product is probably useless.

Comment: @Theo Bendit it is written like this in book you can check kreyszig's functional analysis

Comment: @Ibrahim I absolutely 100% believe you. But, Kreyszig means $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$ whenever he says $\ell^p$. It's not an error or anything like that, it's just shorthand, because people get sick of writing $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$. People don't generally study $(\ell^p, \| \cdot \|_p)$ without its norm anyway. Infinite-dimensional vector spaces tend not to be too interesting unless they're at least equipped with a compatible topology.